# DeNormalizing Value Based on Data Set VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, normalization, denormalization, denormalized

Say I used the following to normalize my data set to [1, -1]:

```
Public Function NormalizeData(values As Double()) As Double()
    Dim min = values.Min
    Dim max = values.Max
    Return values.Select(Function(val) 2 * (val - min) / (max - min) - 1).ToArray
End Function
```

How would I go about de-normalizing a value based on that data set:

```
Public Function DeNormalizeData(baseData As Double(), value As Double) As Double
        Dim min = baseData.Min
        Dim max = baseData.Max
        Return '??
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the inverse of your function: dn=denormalized, n=normalized

`n= 2*((dn-min)/(max-min)) - 1`  adding 1 to both sides

`n+1=2*((dn-min)/(max-min))` divide by 2

`(n+1)/2=(dn-min)/(max-min)` multiply by (max-min)

`((max-min)*(n+1))/2 = dn - min` add min to both

`dn =(((max-min)*(n+1))/2)+min`

You now have the function for de-normalizing, as you can see you need to save the max and min values.

```
public function DeNormalize(n as double, min as double, max as double) as double 
    return (((max-min)*(n+1))/2)+min
end function
```